# Detect ASCII-whitespace in UTF-8 stream

Tags: utf-8, ascii, whitespace

Is it safe to use

```
ch >= '\0' && ch <=' '
```

as a condition that detects ASCII whitespace? (I am ignoring characters like non-breaking space.)

I am thinking of sequences like `0x8? 0x20`, which then would be considered a whitespace, though the first character indicates that the sequence has not ended.

Comment: Your condition matches a number of control characters, not just "whitespace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UTF-8 bytes in a multi-byte sequence will [have their highest bits set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), so no byte in the range of 0x00 - 0x20 can be a part of such sequence. The only bytes that do not have the highest bit set are the stand-alone bytes that represent the first 128 characters of the US-ASCII table.

Therefore, it is safe.